# Cauchy Riemann Conditions -- proving equivalent statements

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be defined in the domain $D\setminus \{0\}$, and let $u=u(r,\theta)$ and $v = v(r,\theta)$ be its real and imaginary parts expressed in polar coordinates with continuous partial derivatives. Prove the following two conditions are equivalent: "$\textit{$f$ is Analytic}$" and "$\textit{The Cauchy-Riemann conditions in the polar form are satisfied}$"

If we express $z$ in polar coordinates then $z = re^{i\theta}$ and $$f(z) = u(r,\theta) + iv(r,\theta)$$ If $\triangle z = (r + \triangle r)e^{i\theta} - re^{i\theta}$ then $\triangle z \to 0 $ if and only if $\triangle r \to 0$ and $$\frac{f(z + \triangle z) - f(z)}{\triangle z} = \frac{u(r+\triangle r, \theta) + iv(r+\triangle r, \theta) -u(r,\theta) - iv(r,\theta))}{\triangle r e^{i\theta}}$$ and $$\lim_{\triangle z \to 0} \frac{f(z + \triangle z) - f(z)}{\triangle z} = \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}\frac{ \partial u(r,\theta)}{\partial r} + \frac{i}{e^{i\theta}}\frac{\partial v(r,\theta)}{\partial r}$$
Similarly, if $\triangle z = re^{i(\theta + \triangle \theta)} - re^{i\theta} = re^{i\theta} \left [ \cos(\triangle \theta) + i\sin(\triangle \theta) - 1\right ]$ then, $$\frac{f(z + \triangle z) - f(z)}{\triangle z} = \frac{u(r,\theta + \triangle\theta) +iv(r,\theta + \triangle \theta) -u(r,\theta) - iv(r,\theta) }{re^{i\theta} \left [ \cos(\triangle \theta) + i\sin(\triangle \theta) - 1\right ]}$$
and by L'Hopital's rule for differentiation with respect to $\triangle \theta$ we get $$\lim_{\triangle z \to 0} \frac{f(z + \triangle z) - f(z)}{\triangle z} = \frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}}{re^{i\theta}i}$$ Assuming $f$ is differentiable, then both limits must equal each other so that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}$$ and $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial r} = -\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}$$ Therefore we have shown the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar coordinates.

Now I am not sure how to use that fact that the partial are continuous to imply analyticity.

Comment: Are you forgetting the condition that the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are continuous?

Comment: Yes I was, but now that I am thinking about that I am not sure how to use that fact that the partial are continuous to imply analyticity.